# Re-initializing JS for filtering for an ajax-loaded Gridview on yii

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, cgridview

I have a page with a drop-down box and a CGridView. When the user selects an item from the drop-down box, an ajax call would be fired to a controller action which calls a `renderPartial` to load a CGridView, to replace the original CGridView.

Everything works fine except when I tried to use the filter on the ajax-loaded CGridView, the original CGridView was brought back. My best guess would be the JS for the original CGridView was still functional, and it was triggered instead.

So my question would be: how do I disable/remove/re-init the JS for the original CGridView, and replace with the proper JS for the ajax-loaded CGridView?

(I have seen people suggesting to add `true` as the forth parameter to `renderPartial` to force the post-processing. But it didn't work, and I am not sure how it works.)

(Sorry if I do not make myself clear in this question. Feel free to comment and I would add in more details if needed. And thank you in advance.)

Comment: Do yo use `$('#your-grid-id').yiiGridView('update')`?

Comment: If you use jquery change to initiate the ajax request, make sure that the "change" is binded to the "select" using "on". eg. $('body').on('change', 'select', function(){
//Ajax Request
})